# Highlight only correct class in a different color in R histogram

Tags: r, histogram, knn

I'm working on a k-Nearest Neighbors classification system, and using a "bucket voting" system that samples predicted classes and then returns a prediction based on which class got the highest number of 'votes' within the sample.

My problem is that I want to automatically generate histograms that have blue bars for the incorrect predictions and a red bar for the correctly predicted class.  Here's a snippet of code:

```
for (class in 14:15) {
     class_test_index <- which(walkTest_labels == class)
     class_test <- as.numeric(walkTest_pred[class_test_index])
     hist(class_test,
           breaks = 0:22,
           col = ifelse(class_test == class, "red", "blue"),
           border = "green",
           main = "Distribution by Classes",
           ylab = "Count",
           xlab = "Class")
      }
```

I've just used two of the classes in my loop to illustrate.  Links to the two histograms that result are here.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXger.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChAE7.png

In both ONLY one bar, the largest one, should be red.  In one of them the correct bar is red, but there's another bar that's red as well.  In the other histogram there are again two bars that are red but they're both wrong.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21858394/324364) for some general guidance on a potentially better way to use `hist` for this sort of thing. However, a bar plot would probably be simpler and make more sense given the discrete nature of your data.

Comment: Can you provide a couple of rows of data frames you are using to generate the histograms?

Comment: Hi Nathan, thanks for asking.  Here is just a simple sample what is being used to create the histogram.  `> head(class_test)
[1] 16  5  5  3 15 15`  As you can see, it's just a vector of classifications.  They range between 1 and 22.

Comment: And thanks to joran, I'm going to check into bar plots and see if that might be an easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found an answer to my own question.  Thanks to Nathan Day for suggesting I look into using the `barplot()` function as this is how I solved the problem.

What I did was to create a vector which contained all of my classes (a list of integers from 1 to 22).  Then within the `for` loop I created another vector that was created by comparing each of these numbers to the class value that was being tested - if the value doesn't match it creates a value of "blue" in the vector, and if correct it creates "red".

When the barplot is created this vector is used as the color parameter, thereby adding red to the correct class and coloring all other classes blue.  Voila!

Here's the code:

```
class_list <- 1:22

for (class in 14:15) {
   class_test_index <- which(walkTest_labels == class)
   class_test <- table(walkTest_pred[class_test_index])
   this_class <- ifelse(class_list == class, "red", "blue")
   barplot(class_test,
        col = this_class,
        border = "green",
        main = "Distribution by Classes",
        ylab = "Count",
        xlab = "Class")
   }
```

If anybody can think of a more elegant way to execute this, that would also be very much appreciated.