# Histogram with different colours using the abline function in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I would like to plot a histogram with different colours and legend.

Assuming the following data:

```html
df1<- rnorm(300,60,5)
```

I have used the following codes to get the histogram plot and the lines using the abline function:

```html
df1<-data.frame(df1)
attach(df1)
hist(M,at=seq(0,100, 2))
abline(v=80, col="blue")
abline(v=77, col="red")
abline(v=71, col="red")
abline(v=68, col="blue")
abline(v=63, col="blue")
abline(v=58, col="blue")
abline(v=54, col="blue")
abline(v=51, col="blue")
abline(v=457, col="blue")
```

Now I want to get the following plot. I wanted to remove the lines, but I was unable to do it. So I do not need to have the lines. 
[image]

Comment: Some points for clarification: 1) Where is object `d1` assigned, or is it a typo? Should `df1<- rnorm(300,60,5)` be `d1`? 2) Presumably you want to remove the vertical lines? Why not just delete the calls to `abline` from your code? 3) your question refers to "different colours and legend" can you please specify what you are expecting? 4) Could you please include the object `M` as a data frame so as to make your question reproducible? 5) What is the argument `at` in the call to `hist`

Comment: Thank you Peter- I have edited it it was typo. You could generate your own data. i expect to get  more or less the same plot. the argument at is to get the x-axis at 2 difference or more..

Comment: I did not delete the abline because  the value v  may change and I want to colour them only between two lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing that with `ggplot2`, `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

First you need to set the colors. I do that with `mutate` and `case_when`. For the plot itself, it's important to remember that if histogram bins are not aligned, you can get different colors on the same bar. To avoid this, you can use `binwidth=1`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- data.frame(data1=rnorm(300,60,5))
df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(color_name=case_when(data1<60              ~ "red",
                              data1>=60 & data1 <63 ~ "blue",
                              TRUE                  ~ "cyan")) 

ggplot(df1,aes(x=data1, fill=color_name)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, boundary = 0, position="dodge") +
  scale_fill_identity(guide = "legend")
```

[image]

**Additional request in comment**

Using `case_when` with four colors:

```
df1 <- data.frame(data1=rnorm(300,60,5))
df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(color_name=case_when(data1<60              ~ "red",
                              data1>=60 & data1 <63 ~ "blue",
                              data1>=63 & data1 <65 ~ "orange",
                              TRUE                  ~ "cyan")) 
ggplot(df1,aes(x=data1, fill=color_name)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, boundary = 0, position="dodge") +
  scale_fill_identity(guide = "legend")
```

[image]

Comment: @user1946911 I edited my code. There was one line missing. The way `ggplot2` works, you need column names. So I put your data in a `data.frame`

Comment: Change the `case_when`

Comment: @user1946911 I added an example with four colors